# Is there a way to catch the moment when Common Lisp package was defined?

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

I want to collect all packages defined during ASDF system loading.

Already tried:

1. to use difference between `(list-all-packages)` before and after system loading, but it is not very convenient, because some systems can be loaded as dependencies of the system I'm inspecting of and I need to make a set extraction.
2. tried to define a `initialize-instance :after ((package package) &rest initargs)` method, but it does not get called when `defpackage` form is evaluated.

Also, when I quickloading an ASDF system, I see the `[package dexador]` in it's output. How does quicklisp do this?

Answer (score 6):

In Quicklisp I used `*macroexpand-hook*`.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about this hook!

Comment: Great this work!

But you also need to process uiop:define-package macro. Here is the fix:

https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-client/pull/191

Comment: It's meant to give some visual feedback about progress, not to be strictly correct. Since packages can be created via many mechanisms (including with `make-package` at compile time) it would require something more careful and thorough to get an exact result.